# Problem with the IK Rigging/ The heel bone control is not connected at it should

Tags: rigging, bones, parent, inverse-kinematics

Noob question: Im new to Blender and I watched videos where they put the IK behind the desire joint (articulation) but when they move it its still connected to the bone. But mine is separated for some reason. It does not have a parent. The leg only has the Inverse Kinematics constraint. I try parenting to the feet, parenting offset to the knee, I try really hard to find the problem but cannot seem to know what it is. How do I make that the control bone follows the Feet.004.L and Leg.003.L

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, are you sure that the videos have the same setup as yours? Because yours is ok but i'm not sure you can block the controller bone with this setup. Maybe point to the videos you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

God, yesterday I was all day  looking everywhere to know what it was; it was so frustrating XD To only just now that I again started to make some tweaks to find more what it was and accidentally fix it. ARRGHH x.x

Idk if everybody wants to know this but I'm gonna show how I fix it. Basically the FeetBone and the FeetControlBone were very horizontal. So I lower the tip to both a little, also I move a little forward the knee so that it could bend on the right side. And did a offset parent the KneeControl to the FeetControl so that when I move the FeetControl so does the KneeControl.

I believe that it did that kind of problem because it didn't know where to bend or which direction to move because the bones where horizontal. (Ironic that I asked a question only to end up answering it myself)## Heading ##

[image]
[image]